# how i can check condition inside navigationOptions in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to set a custom navigation headerLeft property;How i can set the headerLeft property only if the condition is satisfied.otherwise not.I use a StackNavigator in my app. and also cannot access props from inside navigationOptions.

here is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.props.navigation.setParams({goBack: this.goBack, shouldShow: this.state.show });
}


onShow = () => {
  if (this.state.steps >1) {
    this.setState({show:true}, () => {this.props.navigation.setParam({shouldShow:true})} )
  }
}
goBack= () =>{
 this.setState({ steps: this.state.steps - 1 })
}


static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
  let headerLeft = null;
  if (params.shouldShow) {
    headerLeft = <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => params.goBack}>
      <Image source={/* src */} style={Styles.navBarIcon} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  }

  return {
    headerLeft: headerLeft,
    headerTitle: 'Register',
    headerStyle: Styles.navBar,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since navigation options are static and not included inside your class, you cannot simply access states inside it. But you can follow below method.

```
// ------ inside your class -------

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    let headerLeft = null;
    if(params.shouldShow) {
    headerLeft = <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => params.onPressButton()}>
                     <Image source={/* source */} style={Styles.navBarIcon} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
    }

    return {
        headerLeft: headerLeft
    };
};

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ onPressButton: this.onButtonPressedEvent, shouldShow:this.state.show });
}

onButtonPressedEvent = () =>{
// What you want to do when button pressed.
}

onShow = () =>{
   if(this.state.count > 1){
       this.setState({show:true}, () => {this.props.navigation.setParam({shouldShow:true})} )
   }
}
```

Remember to call onShow method when you change the count to make changes in navigation.

Comment: replaced count by steps and remove the onButtonPressedEvent; tried with this and it doesn't worked

Comment: Can you please update your question with new code? Then I can inspect it.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ shouldShow: this.state.show });
}

Comment: onShow = () => {
    alert(this.state.steps);
    if (this.state.steps >1) {
      this.setState({ show: true }, () => { this.props.navigation.setParam({ show: true }) })
    }
  }

Comment: static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    let headerLeft = null;
    if (params.shouldShow) {
      headerLeft = <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => params.onPressButton}>
        <Image source={/* source*/} style={Styles.navBarIcon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    }

    return {
      headerLeft: headerLeft,
      headerTitle: 'Register',
      headerStyle: Styles.navBar,
    };
  };

Comment: Update your questing by editing it. Don't post your code on comments. It's really inconvenient to check it.

Comment: the value of show & shouldShow is empty. i need to change the value of show:true when steps > 1; no navigation from current page all steps are defined in same page.

Comment: Did you add navigationOptions inside the class?

Comment: Okay. What did you mean show and shouldShow values are empty?

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara, Thank you very much. Finally it worked.Thank u so much